# filling the gap of bootstrap 3 grid system with an image in large devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

i have two columns (col-6) for one my sections.
the problem is that the gap between these two columns is so much that i decided to fill this gap by putting a narrow image between them. this is my code:

```
 <div id="Skills">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="section-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-2-left">
                        <ul>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
</ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 section-2-right">
                        <ul>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
    <li class="fade-in-skills slide-in-skills">something</li>
</ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<style>
    #Skills {
        background: rgba(168, 198, 222, .2);
        margin: 100px 50px 0;
        border-radius: 300px 15px 300px 15px;
    }
    
    .section-2 ul {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    .section-2 ul li {
        margin: 77px auto 0;
        opacity: 0;
        font-size: 1.6rem;
        color: #000
    }
    
    .section-2-right, .section-2-left ul li:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 77px;
    }
</style>
```

i am using bootstrap 3. so there is a big gap (something about 400px between the content of these two columns in large devices) and i want to add an image at the middle of them only for large devices. i just wanna know if there's a way to put an image at the middle of these two `col-6` columns or not. so please avoid any other suggestions. how can i do it?
any assistance you can provide would be greatly appreciated.